# populate combo box for edit form in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following form to edit

```
<%= form_for @post  do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>  #This shows correctly
    <%= f.collection_select :product, Product.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

`product` is the column which will save the `id(primary key)` of Product table. How to show the saved value in my select box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `:selected` option

```
<%= f.collection_select :product, Product.all, :id, :name, :selected => @post.product  %>
```

But this works

```
<%= f.collection_select :product, Product.all, :id, :name, :selected => @post.product.id  %>
```

Comment: Then too it is displaying everything

Comment: Yup ..sorry missed id

Comment: @Seting I would suggest you to change the column name to `product_id` instead of just `product`, since you are storing product_id in that column and the name `product` for that column may clash with the name of the association(`has_one` or `has_many`) with `post` model. That's why you have to do `:selected => @post.product.id` because of which 1 extra query is being fired, whereas if you name it just `product_id` then you just have to write `:selected => @post.product_id` and no extra query will be fired